# Probability that $~r_{0}(n)>n/k$

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

For a positive integer greater than $1$, let, under Goldbach's conjecture, $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0, (n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$.
What is the probability $P_{k}(n)$ that $r_{0}(n)>n/k$ where $k$ is a positive real number greater than $1$?
Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\leq x}P_{k}(n)$ exist for all such $k$? Is it always less than $1$?

Comment: This seems extremely difficult to answer.

Comment: I already told you many times that this kind of statement can be answered not under Goldbach conjecture but under the (Cramer) random model. In particular you can generate some random sequences simulating the primes and do numerical checks. In this context, you may want to replace your $r_0(n)$ by things like $\Bbb{E}[\sum_{r \le n} r^{-m} 1_{n+r \in P, n-r \in P}]$. If you want to know what can be answered unconditionally, see the texts on the weak Goldbach conjecture...

Comment: $r$ has to be coprime to $n$ to begin with.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee: yes, and fulfill congruence conditions, namely $n\pm r\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ for $p\leq\sqrt{2n-3}$.

Comment: Never saw that one for goldbach, but you can use $p>3\in 6m\pm 1$ to set valid $r$ values for $n$ so I digress, since comments are really for discussion.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture?r=SearchResults to get the motivation for my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

- if $n$ is 3 mod 6, $r$ needs to be 2 or 4 mod 6
- if $n$ is 0 mod 6, $r$ needs to be 1 or 5 mod 6
- if $n$ is 2 or 4 mod 6,  $r$ needs to be 3 mod 6
- if $n$ is 1 or 5 mod 6, $r$ needs to be 0 mod 6

or $2n-3$ is prime.  $k$ would get lower as we ruled small cases out.

As to the limit I have no clue, except $k$ needs be less than $n\over 2$ unless $n$ is 0 mod 6.